# regular expression a or b

Tags: regex

How do I make regular expression that will match only to r.js or build.js but not to router.js (for example)?
I made this: `/^r.js$|^build.js$/` but I feel like there is a way to remove the ^ and the $. If I remove them, router.js get matched.

Comment: Why would you want to remove `^` and `$`?

Comment: I am looking for a way to make it look better.. If there is one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
/^(r|build)\.js$/
```

'.' should be escaped. If ^ is removed it would match to router.js, if $ is removed it would match r.jsx. So they are needed.

Comment: Well, technically speaking it is good practice to escape the dot if you really mean a dot, but since dot matches anything, it would still match--but it can match more than expected.

Comment: @KennethK. No, *technically speaking* it is not good practice, it is incorrect to fail to escape the dot.  Practically speaking, the difference is sometimes trivial.  A regex is technically incorrect if it accepts either too much or too little.

Comment: @femtoRgon Agreed. In saying "good practice" I was leaning more towards the utility of the character. If I'm searching for some string within a text editor, and I know that strings of the format `build*js` will only ever be literally `build.js`, then it wouldn't matter if I used an escaped or unescaped dot. If, however, I am using the pattern to validate user input, then it would certainly be important as to which one I used. This goes back to my, "but it can match more than expected" comment and your "the difference is sometimes trivial" comment.